# Which non-bold UTF-8 iPhone SDK font can I use here?

Tags: iphone, text

Problem: I create a UILabel with this font:

```
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
```

Now this system font is bold, but I want to display pretty small text, and the text may also contain very strange UTF-8 characters like chinese chars and stuff like that.

So which other fonts are there to use safely, which are NOT bold and suitful to display in small size?

Comment: Like @luvieere said, systemFontOfSize: does not return a bold font, but boldSystemFontOfSize: will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.iphoneruler.net/iphone-fonts) list and choose the one that you like.
Also, you may want to take a look at [this article](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/), it discusses a method of finding all the fonts that are currently installed on the device. As far as I know, `systemFontOfSize` will not return a bold font, `boldSystemFontOfSize` will. Anyway, you may try `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:14.0]`, I think it's pretty easy to read and not bold.